# Getting a frame by frame animation or looped video as a live wallpaper

Tags: android, animation, live, wallpaper

Ok, so I was hired at a company to be an animator for a game company and my boss wants me to make simple animated wallpapers for android....I am not a programmer...and after reading every book I could get my hands on....and only having a month to do this...I only get very little. I can make an animation, and it will even run in the emulator for the phone....but I have no idea how to turn that into a live wallpaper....I went to school for animation and 3d modeling....so this is all greek to me...I'm in dire needs of some assistance!